# How to optimise a FNN/MLP network with MSE (positive only loss) in C

Tags: backpropagation, feedforward-neural-networks, multilayer-perceptrons, mean-squared-error, c

I can create a FNN/MLP network in C but only g-p loss works, where g = ground truth and p = predicted.

What I don't understand is how MSE a positive only loss value can train a back propagation network. Positive only losses result in weights only incrementing in their pre-initialised sign (- or +) thus they just explode or vanish.

Answer (score 1):

> Positive only losses result in weights only incrementing in their pre-initialised sign

No.

In gradient descent, you use the (partial) derivative or the gradient (if you're using vector operations and you have more than one parameter/weight) of the loss function, not the loss function.

So, let's say you have the function $f(x; w) = wx$ that you want to optimize wrt to $w$. Suppose $y$ is the ground-truth label and we use the mean squared error to optimise this function, i.e. $L(x; y; w) = (w x - y)^2$, then the gradient descent step is

$$w \leftarrow w - \alpha \frac{d L}{dw}$$

Now, what is the its derivative of $L$ wrt to $w$, i.e. $\frac{d L}{dw}$? It's

$$2x(w x - y)$$

Now, let's say $x = 1$, $w = 1$ and $y = 2$, then you have that the derivative is

$$2*1(1*1 - 2) = 2 * (-1) = -2$$

Now, let's say $x = 2$, $w = 1$ and $y = 1$, then you have that the derivative is

$$2*2(1 *2 - 1) = 4$$

So, clearly, the derivative can be positive or negative, even if the loss function is always positive. Note that I've used the same $w$ in both examples and the derivatives have different signs.

Comment: i don't accept this as a valid answer, because it is too simplistic and doesn't resemble a real working network at all that uses actual activation derivatives. Out of interest why are you so private tor etc why you don't do anything illegal, this is all machine learning?

My point is if you know the answer show me some example C code and I will tell you if you are wrong or right but anyone can spit out meaningless examples in algebra, to actually implement that and prove it works is another thing.

Comment: @Torrap Asking for code or to implement something is off-topic here. I initially voted to close your post because of this. We focus on the theoretical aspects of AI. Now, I decided to give you an answer that shows that one of your statements was wrong. So, now you know that, if you use MSE, the weights can become more negative or more positive. It should be clear now that what you stated is not a limitation of MSE. Also, if you don't understand backpropagation or gradient descent, I recommend you read about the topic. There are many articles online or books about it

Comment: I don't do anything illegal. Tor can help you to protect your privacy.

Comment: I would suggest you don't understand it because I have actually implemented it in C and have it working, as where you do not.

Comment: @Torrap Feel free to downvote my answer and wait for other answers. It's not a problem for me. This is not going to affect my sleep. But I don't understand why you asked a question if you understood everything and everything works.

Comment: My account is too new to down vote don't worry about it.